# Don't Complete Parse Sign Up Until Picture Chosen

Tags: ios, parse-platform, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I want to add a profile picture to my app that uses Parse when a user signs up, however I don't want to create a brand new ViewController in order to do this.  In the delegate for `shouldBeginSignUp`, I have the basic:

```
- (BOOL)signUpViewController:(PFSignUpViewController *)signUpController shouldBeginSignUp:(NSDictionary *)info {

    BOOL informationComplete = YES;
    // loop through all of the submitted data
    for (id key in info) {
        NSString *field = [info objectForKey:key];
        if (!field || field.length == 0 || ![signUpController.signUpView.additionalField.text containsString:@" "] ) { // check completion
            informationComplete = NO;
            break;
        }


    }

    // Display an alert if a field wasn't completed
    if (!informationComplete) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                                    message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information, including first & last name!"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }

    return informationComplete;

}
```

This will hold up the sign up process until all fields are completed.  What I want to do is upon clicking sign up, have it pop up a `UIActionSheet` asking to choose a profile pic or take a new picture.  After a picture is taken, it would then add that to the PFUser.  How would you suggest doing this?

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Return false if a picture isn't selected, then read about UIImagePickerController (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to always return no from that delegate method, though I'm not 100% sure you'll be able to set a custom file / reference on the user until after it's saved (needs to be tested).

Once your validation is passed you would still return NO but trigger your action to choose the image. When the image is chosen you then dismiss everything and use the `PFUser` to manually complete the signup process (you may need to create a user manually and iterate the fields of the signup controller to populate it with the user choices).